# Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql, import, importerror

I know that it looks like duplicate, but the solutions which I found don't work for me.
I uninstalled MySQL 5.1 and installed 5.6, and I would like to import a previously exported SQL file back. But there is some function which causes an error in that export file.
I found and ran the command:

```
../bin mysql mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force
```

but if I understand, it works only when upgrade, not with install. Is there some solution for me?

I also removed the function definition from import file and import is done. But if I want to redefine that function manually it shows me the same error "can not load from mysql.proc".
Function is here:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `randStr250`(length int) RETURNS varchar(250) CHARSET utf8
begin
  declare s varchar(250);
  declare i tinyint;
  set s="";
  if (length<1 or length>6) then
      set s="Parameter should be in range 1-6. Your value was out of this range.";
  else
    set i=0;
    while i<length do
        set s=concat(s,sha1(now()));
        set i=i+1;
    end while;
  end if;
  return s;
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ok I found this: **mysql\bin mysql_upgrade.exe -u root -pxxx --force** and it works.

Answer (score 168):

Had a similar issue after restorting a db dump from mysql-5.5.29 to mariadb-5.5.41. mysql_upgrade fixed the issue

```
$ mysql_upgrade -u root -pxxx
```

According to the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html),

> You should execute mysql_upgrade each time you upgrade MySQL.

Comment: Just a comment for those using mamp, the same thing applies but mysql_upgrade won't be in your path so run:  `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p root`

Comment: and for mac os users: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -proot`

Comment: Works like a charm after a full debian system upgrade ! Thank you very much !

Comment: `To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.`

Comment: Solved - Upgraded phpMyAdmin as given here - https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Sometimes you should add the --force parameter to the command you wrote.

Comment: Dont forget to use `sudo` in linux.

Comment: I was added the `--force` to make it run. maybe it  becase I was restored a database from an older version.

Comment: mysql_upgrade is deprecated now :(

Comment: this may be a REQUIREMENT for the initial MariaDB installation on RockyLinux, at least until RL is formally approved.

Comment: I had to add `--force` flag to get it to work as expected

Answer (score 2):

Most people that have this problem are recommending upgrading MySQL. If you're in a configuration, like me, in which this happens when you try to set up a SLAVE node to replicate from a MASTER node, you don't really want to mess up with versions.

I mean, in my case I had a Windows MASTER node and was setting up a Linux SLAVE node (so, doing the mysqldump dance first). Since upgrading MySQL is a bit more tricky in Linux (or rather, it's actually better not to do it, to enjoy the stability of Linux packages that, for example, come from your LTS distribution), it's maybe just a good idea to make sure that the MySQL version that you have in your Windows OS is running the same version as your MySQL version in your Linux OS.

Once I made sure both versions were the same, the mysqldump and restore worked, and I could set up a SLAVE node properly without receiving the dreadful error `Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted.`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am using brew so:
`brew upgrade mysql@5.6`  helps

then update profile bash

```bash
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/mike/.bash_profile
```

And restart all terminals.